# How common are low MTU links (<1492) in the public internet?

Tags: ip, tcp

Are there any kind of statistics how common are low MTU links (MTU is below 1492) in the common Internet?

Comment: The Internet uses a MTU size of 1500 bytes.

Comment: The question looks factual to me: what are the statistics? I've given an answer from a recent conference paper with results, and this looks like useful professional networking information to me: I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @Cown IPv6 has a (minimum) MTU of 1280 bytes, IPv4 has a (minimum) MTU of 68 bytes. In Ethernet-based networks the MTU is 1500 but not all connections in the internet are Ethernet-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this paper and its references are what you need, it includes graphs of found sizes and links to datasets.  They report that 98.4% of reachable servers in their survey have a PMTU >= 1500, and have other details for various sizes and metrics.

> Custura, A., Fairhurst, G., & Learmonth, I. (Accepted/In press). Exploring usable Path MTU in the Internet. In *Network Traffic Measurement and Analysis Conference*, TMA 2018 IFIP Open Digital Library.

http://tma.ifip.org/2018/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2018/06/tma2018_paper57.pdf

Comment: From the same paper: "Google data analysing
UDP traversal [36] suggests that up to 64% of access networks
fail to carry 1500 byte UDP packets with the DF flag set"